# datepicker - selected date gets data from database into div

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli, datepicker

I have spent months trying to get this working. I could use some help.

I have a Jquery Datepicker working on my PHP web page. When I click on a day of any month, I need to pull data from the database and display it on a div.

Here is the working Jquery datepicker.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        maxDate: 0,
        dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            var myDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');

            $('#apDiv1').html($.datepicker.formatDate('DD, d', myDate));
            $('#apDiv5').html($.datepicker.formatDate('MM', myDate));
            $('#apDiv7').html($.datepicker.formatDate('yy', myDate));

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "clickdates.php",
                data: { choice: dateText },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(json_data) {
                    $('#apDiv2').html(json_data.dayPowerP[0]).show();
                    $('#apDiv6').html(json_data.monthPowerP[0]).show();
                    $('#apDiv8').html(json_data.yearPowerP[0]).show();
                    $('#apDiv4').load(
                        'dayGraph.php',
                        { choice: dateText }, function() {
                            $(this).show();
                        });
                    $('#apDiv9').load(
                        'monthGraph.php',
                        { choice: dateText}, function() {
                          $(this).show();
                        });
                    $('#apDiv10').load('yearGraph.php',
                        { choice: dateText}, function() {
                          $(this).show();
                        });
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The PHP must be the problem. I have read so much on the new MYSQLi but I am missing something. I can connect to the database without an error, but something is wrong that it will not echo anything into the div. Here is part of the `clickdates.php` file to echo to the `#apDiv2`. The `$choice` isset_POST should come from the date selection on the Datepicker, Then I connect to the database (NOT A PROBLEM connecting to db), then the `$sql` SELECT should do its job to get the Result and echo it. That is my intention.

```
<?php
$choice = (isset($_POST['choice']))
    ? date("Y-m-d",strtotime($_POST['choice'])) : date("Y-m-d");
$conn = new mysqli("xxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxx","xxxxxxxxxx","xxxxxx_ENERGY");

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Database connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT SUM(Whc_daily/1000) AS choice FROM Solar WHERE date = '"
    . $choice . "' group by date";

$result = mysqli_query($sql) or die('sql='.$sql."\n".mysqli_error()); 
$row    = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

$dayPowerP = array( $row['choice']);

$conn->close();
```

Any wisdom will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have used the dataType: 'json' so replace echo $row['choice'].'<br />';  to echo json_encode($row); 
and console the data as console.log(json_data); in jqury success function.

Comment: It must be in the $sql = "SELECT statement, as the webpage only shows "sql=SELECT SUM(Whc_daily/1000) AS choice FROM Solar WHERE date = '2016-09-30' group by date" when I try to load the webpage.

Comment: It was in the sql.... this worked...$sql = "SELECT sum(Whc_daily) AS choice FROM Solar WHERE year(date) = '".$choice."'";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$dayPowerP = array( $row['choice']);

Comment: At Suman Singh... I am curious to understand more about what your first reply regarding the console.log(json_data); could you show me your meaning. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using the json datatype than you have to return value in json encoded format.